# sharing iPhone apps - tell a friend

Tags: iphone, applications

If I have an app on my iPhone and I want to recommend it to someone else who might be interested in downloading and using the app on his/her iPhone - what's the easiest way to do this?

Is there a native way of doing this? Through another app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From iTunes Store on your computer…**

Right click the app in 'your device' > My Apps

Right click & select 'Show in iTunes Store'

[image]

Click the right of the Downloaded button & choose your 'share' method

[image]

or
**From your phone…**

Go to App Store > Updates > My Purchases > All

Tap the app you want to share [not the Open or Cloud button]

Top right is the share button

[image]

*No affiliation to the app used to demonstrate - I just liked the colours ;)*